Probability of choosing 2k balls out of 2n balls
We extract $2k$ balls from an urn with $n$ white balls and $n$ black balls.What is the probability of extracting the same number of balls of each color if we extract the balls with replacement?
Here is my approach:
From each color k balls are extracted. The possible permutations of the white balls are $n^k$ and the same for the black balls. I multiply $n^k$ by $n^k$ and the result by the possible combinations $\binom{2k}{k}$. These are the favorable cases. All the possible outcomes are the variations $_{2n}V_{2k}$.
$$ \frac{n^k\cdot n^k\binom{2k}{k}}{_{2n}V_{2k}} $$

Hi! The first sentence does not make sense to me. Are there $k$ or $n$ black balls?

It sounds like you have two urns, one with all white balls and one with all black.  In that case the probability is $1$.  If that is not correct, please edit the question to make it clear how you are choosing the balls.  Is there one urn with $n$ of each color?  As you are drawing with replacement, you just are flipping $2k$ coins.

Agreed, the question doesn't seem to be correct. If you're extracting $k$ balls from both the white and black pots, then you're always going to have $k$ of each colour, so the probably is $1$.

I think you are overcomplicating it. Ask yourself: What’s the probability of selecting a black ball once - ie on the first selection? And then think about the fact you’re doing it with replacement

Should be $\binom{2k}{k}\frac{1}{2^{2k}}$ if I interpreted this correctly

The answer is $$\frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}(k!)^2}.$$ Note it doesn't depend on the total number of balls $2n$.
Because you're drawing with replacement, and because there are the same number of each colour, there's always a 50/50 chance the ball you draw is either black or white. So each time you draw you simply have an equal choice between two options. So there are $2^{2k}$ total ways to pick the balls.
The cases that have the same number of each colour are those where you 'choose' $k$ of your $2k$ balls to be one colour, leaving the rest to be the other colour. This is $2k$ choose $k$ which is equal to $$\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}.$$
So the probability of drawing the same number of each ball is $$\frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}(k!)^2}.$$

Hmm, interesting okay I'll have another think about it!

@DavidK Hmm! Since my comment the entire answer has been edited to now be correct!

Sorry, I wasn't sure what the right thing to do was. I initially deleted the answer but then saw that it still existed but was hidden, so then I edited it and un-deleted it!

@SBK So I see! I guess both our comments have been made obsolete; I'll delete mine.

@jonnybolton16 In this case, fixing and undeleting seems fine to me. I would just have put a note somewhere that you had done this (either in the answer, or in a comment that replaced the comment that said you were going to do this). The little "edited ___ ago" notice is a clue, but one that's too easy to miss (as I unfortunately demonstrated).
